# Is it advisable to use domain services directly with Spring Integration service activator component?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have few domain services which are needed to be exposed via messaging. I plan to use this domain services directly with the service activator without creating an additional layer of service activator related services that delegate calls to domain services. Is this recommended approach?

The thing that I am worried about is that the domain services will have operations with many parameters and it will become tricky to map message to those parameters. SpEL(Spring Expression Language) might help but not sure of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always use SpEL; such as

```
<int:service activator input-channel="foo"
    expression="@someBean.someMethod(payload)"/>
```

or

```
<int:service activator input-channel="foo"
    expression="@someBean.someOtherMethod(payload.foo, payload.bar)"/>
```

Comment: Is it recommended to use domain service directly with service activator?

Comment: In my case domain services already exist and they being used by many consumers. Some of the domain services contain overloaded methods, for, e.g. getCustomers(PageRequest), getCustomers(Filter,PageRequest), etc. Would it still be possible to use those interfaces directly for gateways and service activators?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by gateway in this context but yes for service activators.

Comment: Yes, you can use existing interfaces as gateway `service-interface`s but methods with more than one parameter will likely need advanced configuration in the `<method/>` element to direct them to appropriate parts of the message (payload, headers etc).

Comment: My concern is not about more than one method parameter but method overaloading in the domain interface. Will the gateway proxy (spring integration generated) be able to make the use of the right configuration (<method/>) specified in the configuration file. Assume three overloaded methods in domain interface with variable number of arguments.

Comment: Right now, it's a little restrictive in that the method metadata is keyed by the method name; this means that you'd have to use something like `<int:method name="send" payload-expression="#args">` and then route by `payload.length` (payload will be an object[]). We are looking at making the method -> message mapping strategy pluggable, allowing you to do your own mapping.